# SSIS: Convert epoch column to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssis, epoch

I got a column with epoch timestamps from 1970-01-01 as datatype numeric in a column called "start_time" (the name contains the "). I'd like to create a new column with the datatype DT_DBTIMESTAMP. I've currently created a Derived Column Transformation where I've set to create a new column with the following expression:

```
DATEADD(s,"start_time",'1970/01/01')
```

I've also tried this one:

```
DATEADD("s",(DT_NUMERIC, 18, 18)"start_time",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

The second one tells me an error that the data type DT_WSTR is not supported for date type, but I cannot understand where DT_WSTR is from since "start_time" is numeric.

Both tests have given me large rows of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This expression works:

```
DATEADD(second, start_time, '1970-01-01')
```

The more complete code is:

```
select start_time, DATEADD(second, start_time, '1970-01-01')
from (select cast(1537009955 as decimal(18, 0)) as start_time) x;
```

Note that the decimal is `decimal(18, 0)`, not `decimal(18, 18)`.  The latter would be a number between 0 and 1.

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/IZRN55901).